# How to use Aggregation and dynamic sorting in Spring data mongo queries

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement mongoTemplate aggregation with Spring on custom spring repository and I have an aggregation like that :

```java
final TypedAggregation aggregation = newAggregation(Result.class,
            lookupOperation,
            addFieldOperation,
            unWindOperation,
            groupOperation,
    ), "inputCollection", Result.class).getMappedResults();
```

I would like to add Spring `SortOperation sort()` and filters only if a condition is validate.
Is there any way to perform adding AggregationOperation to `aggregation` variable?

I found the `AggregationOptions cursor` to pass additional options to the aggregation, but cannot find how to instanciante one with my sorting. Any chance that's the one help me doing that?

Comment: What do you mean with `condition is validate`? Do you know it before perform MongoDB aggregation?

Comment: The `newAggregation` static method, has a version that takes a `List<AggregationOperation>`. Your application can build the list of aggregation operations. If the application logic needs the _sort_ operation, add the `SortOperation` to the list at the desired position. You can control the `AggregationOperation`s needed in the pipeline based upon your application logic. But, note that the way the operations are to be ordered and work together need to be known.

Comment: @prasad_ it wasn't my first thought but it solved my problem and worked. Thanks a lot !